# Number of ways in which $10$ biscuits can be distributed to five beggars seating in a row such that no two consecutive beggars remains without biscuit

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> > If $N$ is the number of ways in which $10$ biscuits can be distributed to five beggars seating in a row such that no two consecutive beggars remains without biscuits, then $N$ is

**Solution:** I've solved this problem using cases

**Case $1$** **(No beggar remains without biscuits)**

So we have to distribute $10$ items to $5$ beggars such that each get at least one which can be done in ${(10-5)+(5-1)\choose 5-1}={9\choose 4}$ ways using star and bars.

**Case $2$: One beggar go empty**

In this case there five possible situation such as $AAAAB$ or $AAABA$ or $AABAA$ or $ABAAA$ or $BAAAA$
So answer to this case is $5\times{(10-4)+(4-1)\choose 4-1}$$=5\times {9\choose 3}$

**Case $3$ Two beggars goes empty:**

In this case there are $6$ possible situation such as $ABABA$ or $BAABA$ or $AABAB$ or $BABAA$ or $BAAAB$ or $ABAAB$ so answer to this case is $6\times {9\choose2}$

**Case $4$ Three Beggars goes empty**

Only one possible case is $BABAB$ and answer to this case is $9\choose1$

So final answer is $771$

**Note:** Here $A$ denotes that beggar get biscuits and $B$ denotes beggar doesnot get anything

**My Doubt: Is there better way to solve this problem? what if there were $15$ beggar and $25$ biscuits?**

Comment: The second way can be principle of inclusion exlusion ,but your method is easier than it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working is correct, but it can be streamlined as summing up the product of two factors

If $k$ people are given some biscuits, there are $k+1$ gaps including ends to place zero biscuit
recipients, thus

$9c4+5c1*9c3+4c2*9c2+3c3*9c1$

### Added

Terms like $9c4,9c3$ etc come directly from Theorem 1 at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)
So if $4$ get biscuits, $9c3$, and $4+1=5$ spaces are there for the zero biscuit recipient's place

### Query

For $25$ biscuits, $15$
people,

$24c14 + 15c1*24c13 + 14c2*24c12 + ...+ 8c8*24c6$

Comment: Then how should i proceed If there were $15$ beggars and $25$ biscuits

Comment: Added as Query in answer